# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 (CMake SFGUI)

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, sfml

I'm trying to build a project with SFML and SFGUI. The project builds until I try to instantiate sfg::SFGUI. When I try I get the following error:

```
/Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/tilemap.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
/usr/bin/clang++    -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -g -Wl,-search_paths_first -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names  CMakeFiles/tilemap.dir/src/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tilemap.dir/src/Camera.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tilemap.dir/src/Player.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tilemap.dir/src/Tile.cpp.o CMakeFiles/tilemap.dir/src/TileMap.cpp.o  -o tilemap /usr/local/lib/libsfml-system.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsfml-window.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsfml-graphics.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsfml-network.dylib /usr/local/lib/libsfml-audio.dylib 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "sfg::SFGUI::SFGUI()", referenced from:
      MyInterface::MyInterface() in main.cpp.o
  "sfg::SFGUI::~SFGUI()", referenced from:
      MyInterface::~MyInterface() in main.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Here is my "MyInterface.h":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <SFGUI/SFGUI.hpp>
#include <SFGUI/Widgets.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class MyInterface {
public:
    void RunInterface();
    void ButtonClick();

private:
    sfg::SFGUI mysfgui;
    // sfg::Window::Ptr m_window;
    // sfg::Button::Ptr m_button;
};

void MyInterface::RunInterface() {
    printf("Interface running!\n");
    // m_window = sfg::Window::Create();
    // auto box = sfg::Box::Create( sfg::Box::Orientation::VERTICAL, 5.f );
    // m_button = sfg::Button::Create( "Click me" );
    // box->Pack( m_button );
    // m_button->GetSignal( sfg::Widget::OnLeftClick ).Connect( std::bind( &MyInterface::ButtonClick, this ) );
}

void MyInterface::ButtonClick() {
    // m_button->SetLabel( "I was clicked" );
}
```

As you can see I've commented everything out besides the SFGUI instantiation.

Here is what my CMake file looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
# Project Specific stuff
set(SOURCE_FILES src/main.cpp src/Camera.cpp src/Player.cpp src/Tile.cpp src/TileMap.cpp src/MyInterface.h)
set(PROJECT_NAME myproject)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES})
message("Building ${PROJECT_NAME}...")
project(${PROJECT_NAME})

# CMake Options
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake_modules")
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin")
if (APPLE)
    message("Found Apple Machine!")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
    set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++")
    set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang++")
    set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "/usr/bin/clang")
endif (APPLE)

# SFML Stuff
find_package(SFML REQUIRED system window graphics network audio)
if (SFML_FOUND)
    message("Found SFML...")
    include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SFML_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # Do I need dir and dirs?
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFML_LIBRARIES} ${SFML_DEPENDENCIES})
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not locate SFML!")
endif (SFML_FOUND)

# SFGUI Stuff
find_package(SFGUI REQUIRED window button widget)
if (SFGUI_FOUND)
    message("Found SFGUI...")
    include_directories(${SFGUI_INCLUDE_DIR} ${SFGUI_INCLUDE_DIRS}) # Do I need dir and dirs?
    target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFGUI_LIBRARIES} ${SFGUI_DEPENDENCIES})
else ()
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not locate SFGUI!")
endif (SFGUI_FOUND)
```

Finally I've compiled SFML with the following options:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/bin/clang" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/bin/clang++" -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;x86_64"
```

and SFGUI:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-stdlib=libc++" -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER="/usr/bin/clang" -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER="/usr/bin/clang++" -DSFGUI_BUILD_EXAMPLES="false" -DSFGUI_BUILD_DOC="false" -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES="i386;x86_64"
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like you are forgetting to actually link the library.. but I'm no cmake expert so I can't tell you why. What does the final linker commandline look like?

Comment: Wouldn't this link the SFGUI library? target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFGUI_LIBRARIES} ${SFGUI_DEPENDENCIES})

Comment: Looks reasonable. But as I said, "not a cmake expert" - what does the *actual* final linker commandline end up looking like?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance here, but where would I find the info you're looking for?

Comment: Observe the final build command that cmake generates. If (for example), it is generating Makefile's, then add VERBOSE=1 when running `make`, etc for other build systems. You can also look in the files that cmake generates to run the real compiler/linker somewhere in your build directory.

Comment: When running cmake itself (or ccmake), does it give you the message "Found SFGUI..."? I don't know SFGUI, but you only requested cmake to find and link the window, button, and widget modules. Does it make a difference if you just `find_package(SFGUI)`?

Comment: It does find SFGUI, I get that message. I've tried running with only find_package(SFGUI) and I get the same result.

Comment: The *actual final linker command line* is in a file that is usually named `link.txt` under the directory `build/<subdirectory>/CMakeFiles/<target>.dir/.` Please check that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help guys, I think I figured out what was wrong. Though I don't know why this works...

I changed:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SFGUI_LIBRARIES} ${SFGUI_DEPENDENCIES})
```

to:

```
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} -lsfgui)
```

I hope this helps someone down the line.

Comment: That's not how you should use CMAKE. Always look for the libraries and pass them.

Comment: I agree it's a bad solution, but at the end of the day it worked.